# How to prevent redirection on form submission in ASP.Net MVC 3, and just stay on the page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, form-submit

I have two forms in one View. One of them does the job of uploading pictures to the database.
I need the whole page -and the data the user has typed into the "other form"- to remain untouched, meanwhile the user could also upload pictures. But it doesn't work.

The problem is that when the user submits the photos, the whole page changes. And worse than that, the new page only contains the "photo uploading" form !! Because upon `Return View();` of the "upload pictures" Action method, it's View is rendered. :/

Look at the action method:

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
          //Upload the pictures .

            return View();
        }
```

Is it possible to achieve the result I need only by changing the return type of the Action method, (maybe ?) in order not to render anything and say just show a message to the user like "Files have been uploaded!" ??

Or should I use Ajax instead ?

Thanks for the advice, in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload files using AJAX but you could use some third-party components that will upload files using hidden iframe which mimics like AJAX. You can google **jquery ajax upload plugin**.

For the other form you can use **Ajax.BeginForm/PartialView** to avoid complete refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the views are strongly typed against a model then you can always pass the model back to the user to "refill" the constant form (probably worst option). Another option (probably best) would be ajax of course.

Comment: Thanks JTMon ;)
I'll go with the Ajax.